# How to disable download dialog box in Firefox in Selenium Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, selenium, firefox

When I am trying to download a file in Firefox, a download dialog box is displayed.I want to disable download dialog box for zip files in Firefox i.e., I want the files to be downloaded automatically. I have tried setting below preferences but still the dialog box is getting displayed.

```
        let driver: WebDriver;
        var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
        var ff = require("selenium-webdriver/firefox");
        const FirefoxProfile = require('firefox-profile');
        var fp = await new FirefoxProfile();
        var capabilities = await webdriver.Capabilities.firefox();
        var options = await new ff.Options();

        let strDownloadFolder = await path.join(process.env.USERPROFILE, "Downloads");
        
        await fp.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
        await fp.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
        await fp.setPreference("browser.download.dir", strDownloadFolder);
        await fp.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/zip,application/octet");
        await fp.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip,application/octet");
        await fp.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        await fp.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
        await fp.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
        await fp.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);
        await fp.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
        await fp.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
        await fp.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", false);

        await fp.encoded(function (err:any, encodedProfile:any) {
            capabilities.set("firefox_profile", encodedProfile);
        });

        driver = await new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(capabilities).build();
```

Can someone help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the preferences you defined

```
await fp.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", "application/zip,application/octet");   
await fp.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/zip,application/octet");
```

Try adding additional MIME types of zip file.
So, additionally to `application/zip,application/octet` try adding also the following MIME types:

- application/octet-stream
- multipart/x-zip
- application/zip
- application/zip-compressed
- application/x-zip-compressed